# Starting Iris Seeds Indoors

Tags: germination, sprouting, irises, cold-stratification

I placed some bearded iris seeds in moistened commercially produced starting/potting mix at the end of January and placed them in the refrigerator. Per some instructions I had found on YouTube, I allowed them to sit in the fridge for about 6 weeks. I then took them out of the fridge and I've placed them in a sunny, but coolish window. The temperature in the window is typically around 50-70°F degrees with an average of around 65°F. I do try to keep them watered based on how moist their soil feels.

So far, I haven't gotten any sprouts at all. In a few areas, I have tried to dig up a seed or two and I have not seen any signs of sprouting.

How long should I wait for signs of sprouting and are there any things I can do to encourage sprouting?

Comment: You did everything right. The seeds are suspect. Let a bunch sit in a plastic bag with some moisture and some light for 2 weeks. This is the method to measure 'germination rate'.

Comment: @Vorac thank you for the tip! I will try this with some of my leftover seeds. The place I bought them from is no longer in business and maybe this is why :(

Comment: No, do not give upon the original seller. Allow them 2 weeks of doubt